# Paypal IPN will just not work properly

Tags: paypal, postback, paypal-ipn, cgi-bin

This is my code:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) { // HTTP ERROR
    echo 'HTTP ERROR';
} else {

    fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
    while (!feof($fp)) { $res = fgets ($fp, 2048); }

        if (strpos ($res), "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            switch ($transaction_type) {
                case "subscr_payment": 
                    if ($payment_status == "Completed" &&strtolower($receiver_email) == strtolower($receiverEmail)&&$currency=$payment_currency)
```

Earlier I had tried entering the `trim` statement into this line:

```
if (strpos ($res, "VERIFIED") !== false)
```

I changed it to:

```
if (strcmp (trim($res), 'VERIFIED') == 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 'Connection: close' header (which ends with `\r\n`) is correctly followed by a blank line (i.e. another `\r\n`), being the last header, but so is the previous header ('Content-Length'). So the 'Connection: close' header is being seen as part of the payload. Remove the blank line from the previous header, i.e. change the 2nd-last `\r\n\r\n` to `\r\n`. In fact I would change them both, and add another print of `\r\n` after the last header, so you won't break it like this again.

Comment: ***Moderator Note*** *Comments under this post have been removed due to digressing into more noise than signal. Please keep comments brief, on topic and most of all professional.*